# An unexpected error occurred: package.json Unexpected token

Tags: reactjs, npm

I create a website with ReactJs. and Its worked correctly. but now when I run the project **yarn dev** or **npm run dev** I got this error

```
yarn run v1.22.17
error An unexpected error occurred: "C:\\Users\\my location\\package.json: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\Users\\my location \\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

and this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.6",
    "@react-pdf-viewer/default-layout": "^3.6.0",
    "@react-pdf-viewer/thumbnail": "^3.6.0",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-addons-update": "^15.6.3",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-cookies": "^0.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-media-recorder": "^1.6.6",
    "react-multi-date-picker": "^3.3.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-select": "^5.4.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.3",
    "react-transition-group": "^4.4.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.8",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-addons-update": "^0.14.21",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/react-google-recaptcha": "^2.1.5",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.4",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^1.3.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
    "postcss": "^8.4.14",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.4",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "vite": "^2.9.9"
  }
}
```

I also use [eslint](https://eslint.org/play/) and add my package.json content to this site and I got this error
on colon after "name":"test"

> 2:9
>
> Parsing error: Unexpected token

:

and also remove node_module and reinstall the package with npm install. but the error still occurs.

Comment: `Unexpected token < in JSON` - that usually happens with `404`: you request a JSON, but get an HTML "not found" document. Some network error, maybe?

Comment: @mbojko but Why error throws in package.json?